# question related to dictionary and list conversion

Tags: python

I have nested list. Now, I want to convert it into dictionary.
nested list always contain only two items in my case.

```
list1 = [['a','b'],['c','d']]
list2=[]
for i in list1:
    list2.append({'name':i[0],'value':i[1]}) //it work correct but i want to optimize that code.

o/p of above code(this i want): [{ 'name': 'a','value': 'b'}, {'name': 'c', 'value': 'd'}]
```

Anyone can tell. How to optimize the above code. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure, you could do a list comprehension, but really there's nothing particularly inefficient about your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a strange data structure to have a list of dictionaries like this in my opinion, but you can do it efficiently performance-wise like this:

```
list1 = [['a','b'],['c','d']]
[{"name": x[0], "value": x[1]} for x in list1]
```

Comment: it gives [{'value': 'b', 'name': 'a'}, {'value': 'd', 'name': 'c'}].
Is it possible to convert it into dictionary.
like this...........{{'value': 'b', 'name': 'a'}, {'value': 'd', 'name': 'c'}}. @Sven H.

Comment: No that's not a valid data structure in python, a dictionary needs to be constructed from key:value pairs which the outer dict in your proposed structure does not

Answer (score 0):

Using [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) and dictionary + list comprehension:

```
from itertools import cycle

list1 = [['a','b'],['c','d']]
k = cycle(['name', 'value'])
print([{next(k): v for v in x} for x in list1])

# [{'name': 'a', 'value': 'b'}, {'name': 'c', 'value': 'd'}]
```

Here, `cycle` creates an infinite iterator taking items in a cyclic manner - `name, value, name, value, name,...`. `next()` on this iterator takes value out on each iteration.

Comment: can you explain it.

Comment: I've added explanation and a link for further reference.